# Unable tu map FastAPI List[], Set() through SQLModel into Postgres

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic, sqlmodel

I'm doing my personal portfolio API with **FastAPI** and decided to try **SQLModel**. It feels so intuitive and i love it so far, but i encountered a problem that I have struggling with for days, trying to understand how to make it right.

I have a Project model:

```
from datetime import datetime
from typing import List, Optional, Set
from sqlmodel import SQLModel, Field


class ProjectBase(SQLModel):
    name: Optional[str]
    summary: Optional[str]
    description: Optional[str]
    category: Set[str] = ()
    award: Optional[str] = None
    url: Optional[str] = None
    published: datetime = datetime.utcnow()
    image: str = "placeholderMainImage"
    images: List[str] = []
    learning: Optional[str]
    tech: Optional[str]
    tools: Optional[str]



class Project(ProjectBase, table=True):
    id: int = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    created_at: datetime = Field(default_factory=datetime.utcnow)
    updated_at: datetime = Field(default_factory=datetime.utcnow)
```

FastAPI works fine and I checked  **localhost:8000/docs** and is making the types validation correctly:

```
    {
  "name": "string",
  "summary": "string",
  "description": "string",
  "category": [],
  "award": "string",
  "url": "string",
  "published": "2021-10-04T20:43:26.472364",
  "image": "placeholderMainImage",
  "images": [],
  "learning": "string",
  "tech": "string",
  "tools": "string",
  "id": 0,
  "created_at": "2021-10-04T21:01:30.048Z",
  "updated_at": "2021-10-04T21:01:30.048Z"
}
```

When i made the POST request with the above query, I get **internal server error**:

```
invalid input for query argument $4: (expected str, got set)
```

Unfortunately, SQLModel by design converts any strange type into VARCHAR at table creation, making imposible to use the List or Set functionality:

```
   CREATE TABLE project (
         name VARCHAR, 
         summary VARCHAR, 
         description VARCHAR, 
         category VARCHAR, 
         award VARCHAR, 
         url VARCHAR, 
         published TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, 
         image VARCHAR, 
         images VARCHAR, 
         learning VARCHAR, 
         tech VARCHAR, 
         tools VARCHAR, 
         id SERIAL, 
        created_at TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, 
        updated_at TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, 
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
 )
```

I have understood that postgres have some array types like: **integer[]** and **text[]** that could handle this case scenario for the category and images fields.
Tried manually change the table columns types with same result.

tried to post category and images as str:

```
    {
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [
        "body",
        "category"
      ],
      "msg": "value is not a valid set",
      "type": "type_error.set"
    },
    {
      "loc": [
        "body",
        "images"
      ],
      "msg": "value is not a valid list",
      "type": "type_error.list"
    }
  ]
}
```

It will be so sad to not be able to use such amazing features to sanitize the data I'm receiving. I looked on internet and can't find yet anything related or an example using List and Set with SQLModel

¿What can I do to support this case scenario?

PD: I'm also using asyncpg

Answer (score 6):

I got it working for Lists, but not for Sets on a postgres database. The problem lies in when results are mapped back to your Project class. Here is my full code.

```
from datetime import datetime
from typing import List, Optional, Set
from sqlalchemy.sql.schema import Column
from sqlmodel import SQLModel, Field, create_engine, Session, select, String, ARRAY 
from fastapi import FastAPI

class ProjectBase(SQLModel):
    name: Optional[str]
    category: Set[str] = Field(default=None, sa_column=Column(ARRAY(String())))
    images: List[str] = Field(default=None, sa_column=Column(ARRAY(String())))


class Project(ProjectBase, table=True):
    id: int = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)

engine = create_engine("postgresql://postgres:mysecretpassword@localhost:5432/testdb")

new_proj = Project(
    name=f"{str(datetime.time(datetime.utcnow()))}", 
    category=("hi", "hello", "cat3"), 
    images=["img1", "img2"] 
)

app = FastAPI()

@app.on_event("startup")
def on_startup():
    SQLModel.metadata.create_all(engine)
    print("BEFORE REFRESH:", new_proj)
    with Session(engine) as session:
        session.add(new_proj)
        session.commit()
        session.refresh(new_proj)
    print("AFTER REFRESH:", new_proj)

@app.get("/", response_model=List[Project])
def home():
    with Session(engine) as session:
        projects = session.exec(select(Project)).all()
        return projects
```

I have simplified your `Project` class a bit. Upon starting uvicorn running this, I get the following output (ref to the `@app.on_event("startup")`):

```
BEFORE REFRESH: name='17:17:38.090595' category={'hoi', 'cat3', 'hello'} images=['img1', 'img2'] id=None
AFTER REFRESH: id=7 category=['hoi', 'cat3', 'hello'] images=['img1', 'img2'] name='17:17:38.090595'
```

Note that the difference in the `category` value, starting with { (denoting a set) before the object is refreshed from the database, and starting with [ after the object is refreshed from the database.

I have tried all kinds of things but to no avail. Only thing I could think of (but couldn't find anything about) was some sort of custom mapping rule for `sqlalchemy`. I don't know enough about that package though to really understand what I am looking for. Hope this helps at least! I learnt a lot either way :)

Comment: Wow, thanks, i will try and let you know about.!!

Comment: Thanks, it worked, so what i understand you are explicitly telling SQLModel to use the  SQLAlchemy *ARRAY(String())* . for the moment i will use this array. thanks Let's see if someone knows something about Set()

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should consider implementing a non relational database for this kind of db inserts.

But if you insist SQL model has a solution so check the following link:
https://github.com/tiangolo/sqlmodel/issues/178